# BigNumber() not a base 16 number error while calling contract function

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I am trying to call very simple smart contract function, however the result is the following error:

```
BigNumber Error: "new BigNumber() not a base 16 number: "
```

I follow the course on the link: [here](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/99/Interacting-with-a-Smart-Contract-through-Web3.js-(Tutorial))

```
Coursetro.getInstructor(function(error, result){
   if(!error)
   {
       $("#instructor").html(result[0]+' ('+result[1]+' years old)
       console.log(result);
   }
   else
       console.error(error);
});
```

Expected result is array.

Comment: Show the full contract and JS file.

Comment: What version of web3.js are you using?